# Service Area Default Breaks: Single vs Multiple Breaks

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network-dataset, service-area

[image]

I have created a road network dataset, loading my facilities, and am running network analyst to identify services areas.

Polygon Generation for all versions is set to Detailed,Trim, 100 meters, Merge by Break Value, Disks.

For some reason, if I ask for one specific break, I get a different polygon generation than if I had done multiple breaks.

Both lines showing are the 7 minute break, so it's not a matter of choosing the wrong break.

Any idea as to why the service area would change if I specify a single break versus multiple breaks and only showing one break from that group?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer from Esri support.

When you set the trim to a specific distance it adds that distance to the last break you specify.

If you only ask for one break (7 minutes) then you'll have 7 minutes with the trim of 100m.

If you ask for Breaks at 7 and 8 minutes... the 8 minute break will have the 100m trim associated with it.

In addition, for the most accurate representation of the service area, the Line layer actually shows the specific location of where you hit the break you've requested.